# Highlight Every other row that contains information in column A vba

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I was hoping you guys could help me figure something out. I am trying to get excel to highlight every other row that contains any information in column A

so it would look like this:

[image: img]

I haven't been able to make any proper headway into this but I was hoping you guys might be able to give me some basic direction.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA, just use *conditional formatting*.
Mark the Range, go to Conditional formatting, add a new rule with rule type "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and enter

```
=AND($A1<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=1)
```

(depending on the regional setting, you might have to exchange the `","` with `";"` - same syntax as a regular formula)

Then, click the "Format" button and select a fill color.

Answer (score 0):

## Convert a range into a table in Excel:

You can make your range of data into a **table** (including auto-formatting):

1. Select (highlight) the cells (including the heading if there is one).
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

There are several ways you can then customize your table, such as the options on the ribbon.

[image: img2]

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Create or delete an Excel table**](https://support.office.com/article/create-or-delete-an-excel-table-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664)
- Office.com : [**Overview of Excel tables**](https://support.office.com/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)
- Several other tutorials and examples on [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20tables%20tutorial).